# Why is pylab.plot putting points elsewhere it should? Shall I use another function?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm studying a function
y = x * sqrt((x ** 2) - 1) / (x ** 2 + 1)

If I don't take care of its definition domain, writing this Python code to display its graph, I receive a deserved error:

```py
import pylab as pl
from numpy import *

pl.style.use('bmh')

# Df = R
Df = [-5 + k/10 for k in range(100)] # from -5 to -5 by 0.1 steps

X = Df
Y = [x * sqrt((x ** 2) - 1) / (x ** 2 + 1) for x in X]   # Pour tout x ∈ X, calculer y = f(x)

print(len(X), "values for X:", X)
print(len(Y), "values for Y:", Y)

pl.plot(X, Y, color='red', label = r'$\mathscr{C}_f$') # Place le Cf comme légende du graphe
pl.legend(fontsize = 18) # Cet appel est important : sans, la légende ne s'affichera pas
```

```
100 values for X: [-5.0, -4.9, -4.8, -4.7, -4.6, -4.5, -4.4, -4.3, -4.2, -4.1, -4.0, -3.9, -3.8, -3.7, -3.6, -3.5, -3.4, -3.3, -3.2, -3.1, -3.0, -2.9, -2.8, -2.7, -2.6, -2.5, -2.4, -2.3, -2.2, -2.1, -2.0, -1.9, -1.7999999999999998, -1.7000000000000002, -1.6, -1.5, -1.4, -1.2999999999999998, -1.2000000000000002, -1.1, -1.0, -0.9000000000000004, -0.7999999999999998, -0.7000000000000002, -0.5999999999999996, -0.5, -0.40000000000000036, -0.2999999999999998, -0.20000000000000018, -0.09999999999999964, 0.0, 0.09999999999999964, 0.20000000000000018, 0.2999999999999998, 0.40000000000000036, 0.5, 0.5999999999999996, 0.7000000000000002, 0.7999999999999998, 0.9000000000000004, 1.0, 1.0999999999999996, 1.2000000000000002, 1.2999999999999998, 1.4000000000000004, 1.5, 1.5999999999999996, 1.7000000000000002, 1.7999999999999998, 1.9000000000000004, 2.0, 2.0999999999999996, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4000000000000004, 2.5, 2.5999999999999996, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9000000000000004, 3.0, 3.0999999999999996, 3.1999999999999993, 3.3000000000000007, 3.4000000000000004, 3.5, 3.5999999999999996, 3.6999999999999993, 3.8000000000000007, 3.9000000000000004, 4.0, 4.1, 4.199999999999999, 4.300000000000001, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.699999999999999, 4.800000000000001, 4.9]
100 values for Y: [-0.9421114395319916, -0.9398113759382029, -0.9373732787465292, -0.9347860331756372, -0.9320373995935088, -0.9291138763121071, -0.9260005427973046, -0.9226808800944472, -0.9191365646819614, -0.9153472312576224, -0.9112901991076275, -0.906940155674102, -0.9022687896804243, -0.8972443646434369, -0.8918312217313193, -0.8859891986319921, -0.8796729482726837, -0.8728311377393453, -0.8654055034061587, -0.8573297328647643, -0.8485281374238571, -0.8389140702989794, -0.8283880345190419, -0.8168354101509777, -0.8041237113402062, -0.7900992577510069, -0.77458310873153, -0.7573660557643617, -0.7382023882360264, -0.716802017680235, -0.6928203230275509, -0.6658446724656546, -0.6353757826597258, -0.6008004124492233, -0.5613481346874964, -0.5160156871153361, -0.463416978364385, -0.40143535397001834, -0.3262253892152854, -0.22809200291635415, -0.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, 0.0, 0.22809200291635368, 0.3262253892152854, 0.40143535397001834, 0.4634169783643853, 0.5160156871153361, 0.5613481346874963, 0.6008004124492233, 0.6353757826597258, 0.6658446724656546, 0.6928203230275509, 0.7168020176802349, 0.7382023882360264, 0.7573660557643617, 0.77458310873153, 0.7900992577510069, 0.8041237113402061, 0.8168354101509777, 0.8283880345190419, 0.8389140702989795, 0.8485281374238571, 0.8573297328647644, 0.8654055034061586, 0.8728311377393454, 0.8796729482726836, 0.8859891986319921, 0.8918312217313193, 0.8972443646434368, 0.9022687896804246, 0.9069401556741022, 0.9112901991076275, 0.9153472312576224, 0.9191365646819613, 0.9226808800944472, 0.9260005427973046, 0.9291138763121071, 0.9320373995935088, 0.9347860331756371, 0.9373732787465293, 0.9398113759382029]
```

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
Y = [x * sqrt((x ** 2) - 1) / (x ** 2 + 1) for x in X]   # Pour tout x ∈ X, calculer y = f(x)

but with the courtesy of Pylab, accompanied by this graph, that is the one I'm looking for:

[image]

I duly correct my definition domain and rerun my code.

```py
# Df = ]-inf, -1] U [1, +inf[
Df1 = [-5 + k/10 for k in range(40)] # from -5 to -1 by 0.1 steps
Df2 = [+1 + k/10 for k in range(40)] # from +1 to +5 by 0.1 steps
Df = Df1 + Df2

X = Df
Y = [x * sqrt((x ** 2) - 1) / (x ** 2 + 1) for x in X]   # Pour tout x ∈ X, calculer y = f(x)

print(len(X), "values for X:", X)
print(len(Y), "values for Y:", Y)

pl.plot(X, Y, color='red', label = r'$\mathscr{C}_f$') # Place le Cf comme légende du graphe
pl.legend(fontsize = 18) # Cet appel est important : sans, la légende ne s'affichera pas
```

```
80 values for X: [-5.0, -4.9, -4.8, -4.7, -4.6, -4.5, -4.4, -4.3, -4.2, -4.1, -4.0, -3.9, -3.8, -3.7, -3.6, -3.5, -3.4, -3.3, -3.2, -3.1, -3.0, -2.9, -2.8, -2.7, -2.6, -2.5, -2.4, -2.3, -2.2, -2.1, -2.0, -1.9, -1.7999999999999998, -1.7000000000000002, -1.6, -1.5, -1.4, -1.2999999999999998, -1.2000000000000002, -1.1, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 2.9, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4.0, 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9]
80 values for Y: [-0.9421114395319916, -0.9398113759382029, -0.9373732787465292, -0.9347860331756372, -0.9320373995935088, -0.9291138763121071, -0.9260005427973046, -0.9226808800944472, -0.9191365646819614, -0.9153472312576224, -0.9112901991076275, -0.906940155674102, -0.9022687896804243, -0.8972443646434369, -0.8918312217313193, -0.8859891986319921, -0.8796729482726837, -0.8728311377393453, -0.8654055034061587, -0.8573297328647643, -0.8485281374238571, -0.8389140702989794, -0.8283880345190419, -0.8168354101509777, -0.8041237113402062, -0.7900992577510069, -0.77458310873153, -0.7573660557643617, -0.7382023882360264, -0.716802017680235, -0.6928203230275509, -0.6658446724656546, -0.6353757826597258, -0.6008004124492233, -0.5613481346874964, -0.5160156871153361, -0.463416978364385, -0.40143535397001834, -0.3262253892152854, -0.22809200291635415, 0.0, 0.22809200291635415, 0.3262253892152852, 0.40143535397001845, 0.463416978364385, 0.5160156871153361, 0.5613481346874964, 0.6008004124492231, 0.6353757826597259, 0.6658446724656546, 0.6928203230275509, 0.716802017680235, 0.7382023882360264, 0.7573660557643617, 0.77458310873153, 0.7900992577510069, 0.8041237113402062, 0.8168354101509777, 0.8283880345190419, 0.8389140702989794, 0.8485281374238571, 0.8573297328647643, 0.8654055034061587, 0.8728311377393453, 0.8796729482726837, 0.8859891986319921, 0.8918312217313193, 0.8972443646434369, 0.9022687896804243, 0.906940155674102, 0.9112901991076275, 0.9153472312576224, 0.9191365646819614, 0.9226808800944472, 0.9260005427973046, 0.9291138763121071, 0.9320373995935088, 0.9347860331756372, 0.9373732787465292, 0.9398113759382029]
```

But with this graph, that doesn't please me:

[image]

You can see that in the second example, X and Y sets don't hold values for x between ]-1, 1[.

`plot` acts as if it has to join points that aren't linked, together.

It's absolutely not what I'm willing it to do!

Am I in front of the wrong method and I should choose another one? Or is it a trouble with the parameters I'm sending to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`plot` connects the given points with straight lines to generate the "curve". That said, it simply does not "know" that your function is not continuous and points (-1.1, approx. -0.25) and (1, 0) should not be connected.

But, you can easily fix that. `plot` will neither connect nor complain about `NaN` points, so by adding e.g. zero to your domain, you would get a `NaN` value from [`np.sqrt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sqrt.html), as you can see in the docs.

```python
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl

pl.style.use('bmh')

# Df = ]-inf, -1] U [1, +inf[
Df1 = [-5 + k/10 for k in range(40)] # from -5 to -1 by 0.1 steps
Df2 = [+1 + k/10 for k in range(40)] # from +1 to +5 by 0.1 steps
Df = Df1 + [0] + Df2

X = Df
Y = [x * np.sqrt((x ** 2) - 1) / (x ** 2 + 1) for x in X]   # Pour tout x ∈ X, calculer y = f(x)

print(len(X), "values for X:", X)
print(len(Y), "values for Y:", Y)

pl.plot(X, Y, color='red', label = r'$\mathscr{C}_f$') # Place le Cf comme légende du graphe
pl.legend(fontsize = 18) # Cet appel est important : sans, la légende ne s'affichera pas
pl.show()
```

And the result is what you want

[image]